# how to use lag function in the calculation in sas

Tags: function, time, sas, lag

I"m lost with lag function; Here below is what I'm trying to do.
[image]

```
data out;
    set in;
    by a;
 y = 0.5 ; 
 y =  lag(y) * ( 1 - x);  end;
run;
```

"in" table only have X and sequence value A ,What I want is to create "out" table with y value starting  with "0.5" then the rest of Y would coming from the calculation of the previous Y value multiply with (1-X)    => Y = lagY * ( 1 - X )

I'm trying to use lag function but it does give me what I want ..

please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you add more data to your table for the A and X columns UNTIL the value of X = 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LAG function works against the data being read in.  Since the variable y doesn't exist in the input dataset, the LAG function won't work as you want.

Instead use the RETAIN statement to hold the previous value of y.

```
data in;
input A x;
datalines;
1   0.25
2   0.16
3   0.1
4   0.5
5   0.6

data out;
    set in;
    by A;
retain y 0.5;
if _n_>1 then y=y*(1-x); 
run;
```

Comment: Probably worth explaining that RETAIN Y 0.5; initializes y to a value of 0.5 in the FIRST iteration, and then beyond that it maintains whatever value it had from the previous iteration

Comment: Thank you , never knew that before , this is great tips :)